# ArcCatalog crashing on start-up

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

I managed to crash my ArcCatalog trying to bring multiple feature classes over into a new file geodatabase \ feature dataset. I tried starting up the program again and during the start up it crashed. I have restarted my computer yet ArcCatalog will still crash upon start up. I am unsure how to solve this problem apart from uninstalling ArcGIS for Desktop which I do not want to do. Has anyone had any experience with this issue and/or know a way to only re-install ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often issues with ArcCatalog (or many other ArcGIS Desktop applications) crashing or having issues while opening can be solved by deleting or renaming the `Normal.gxt` file (`Normal.mxt`, `Normal.sxt` etc. for other ArcGIS Desktop apps).

Browse to `%appdata%\Desktop10.5\` (change the `10.5` to whichever version you are running)

[image]

Select the `ArcCatalog` (or relevant app) folder

[image]

Select the relevant `Normal` template file, and delete it or rename it

[image]

Restart your ArcGIS Desktop application. The `Normal` template file will be re-created when the application is opened, and whatever was causing the crash or loading issues will hopefully be gone.

This method can also be used for trouble-shooting slow loading, or problem third-party toolbars etc.